# Requiring Java Classes in LuaJ

Tags: java, c, lua, require, luaj

I'm attempting to make a game library in Java that uses Lua for the scripts.  The real issue appears when I try to require a Java class (that is inside of a jar), and whenever I try to do so, I get an error much like the one below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.luaj.vm2.LuaError: @/C:/xampp/htdocs/LevelDesigner/Projects/Lua Test/bin/levels/Test.lua:2 module
'resources.GameLevel' not found: resources.GameLevel
no field package.preload['resources.GameLevel']
```

How can I require a Java class that is within a jar?  Right now it seems that, with Lua, I can only require .lua files, and not .class files.  This is obviously problematic as Java files are compiled down to class files...And that is what I need to require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is to use luajava.bindClass as opposed to require in all of your Lua scripts.